# Removing Docker data without affecting relevant cache?

Tags: docker

When image is built using `docker buildx bake --load some-target`, it saves build cache, which can later be reused, making next re-build much faster.

Though this can take too much space as cache/images can grow if not controlled.

So I want to understand, which commands should I use to remove stuff that is irrelevant and keep relevant cache, so builds are still fast.

I see a couple of options:

1. If I use `docker system prune -a`. It will remove most stuff, including cache and then builds are done from scratch.
2. If I use `docker system prune`, it will remove dangling images, also dangling cache (did not find any documentation about what is dangling build cache?) and it looks like even if some cache is removed, my build time is not affected by it, it still uses relevant cache.
3. Can also use command to clear cache directly with `docker buildx prune --filter until=24h`. This one looks like it removes same "dangling cache", but only after its older then in specified filter.

What would be recommended approach to keep docker from growing out of control, but still providing cache?

Context: I have self hosted runners where most docker data can be safely deleted as its used only to either build or test application. So the only relevant part is to make sure cache is still there, to make builds fast.

Comment: @KamilCuk I don't want to preserve any containers. There can be many different containers being used on a runner. Also this looks like a hack.

Comment: @KamilCuk not true. Cache is not the same as an image. I deleted all images in my env, and my build still used cache and was super fast.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go with option one and three combined. So it deletes everything, but keeps only most recent data, which also keeps relevant cache (more or less).

So can simply do `docker system prune -a --filter until=24h`